# system commands in future/promises in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, vcf-variant-call-format

I have the below server.R code in shiny app where a system command is run inside future which gives an `output.vcf` file.  Upon creation of this file the progress bar is removed and a second system command is run to convert `out.vcf` to `out.txt`

The system commands are used as R could not read huge vectors on a 32Gb machine. Hence some system commands are used to process the data.

The output produced in the first system command i.e. `out.vcf` has to be rendered to `downloadHandler`  and the output from the second command `out.txt` has to be returned to `renderDataTable`.

Could someone suggest an efficient way of doing this? possibly running both the system commands inside the `future()` and returning the outputs to `downloadHandler` and `renderDataTable`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
file_rows <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$run, {
  prog <- Progress$new(session)
  prog$set(message = "Analysis in progress",
    detail = "This may take a while...",
    value = NULL)

  path <- input$uploadFile$datapath
  nrows <- input$nrows

  future({
    system(paste(
      "cat",
      input$uploadFile$datapath,
      "|",
      paste0("head -", input$nrows) ,
      ">",
      "out.vcf"
    ),
      intern = TRUE)
   read.delim("out.vcf")
  }) %...>%
    file_rows() %>%
    finally(~prog$close())
})



observeEvent(req(file_rows()), {
updateTabsetPanel(session, "input_tab", "results")
    rows_input <- file_rows()

    system(paste(
      "cat",
      rows_input,
      "|",
      paste(some system command"),
      ">",
      "out.txt"
    ),
      intern = TRUE)

##How could we render the content of "out.txt" from the above system command to datatable in the below code#######  
    output$out_table <-
      DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
        out.txt,
        options = list(
          searching = TRUE,
          pageLength = 10,
          rownames(NULL),
          scrollX = T
        )
      ))

##How could we render the content of "out.vcf" from the first system command to downloadHandler in the below code#######    
output$out_VCFdownList <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0("output", ".vcf")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.vcf("out.vcf from first system command ", file)
      }
    )
  })
```

Comment: Side note: you should probably use `shQuote` around your variable arguments within `system`. Do you need to return read-in and actually return the *contents* of `"out.vcf"`, or would it be sufficient to return just the filename signalling that its creation is complete? Then, your second `system` call could do `"cat out.csv | ..."` directly instead of trying to `cat` improperly formatted (for shell work) output?

Comment: It is not required to return the contents of `out.vcf`, since i am not able to write the code signalling the completion, i am returning the contents of `out.vcf`. It would be great that could be done so that the second system command could directly read from the file.

Comment: are you planning to add a minimum reproducible example? and could you explain what the downloadhandler is required for? (users dont have access to the directories where the out.vcf is stored?)

Comment: The code is a small piece from a big shiny app and i find it difficult to create a reproducible example.  The shiny app runs on our local server and the users are allowed to used the app via the url. So the directory where the `out.vcf` is written from the first system command is not physically available to the users to browse to the disk and the file can be retrieved only from the downloadhandler.

Comment: In the above code, i have used `read.delim("out.vcf")` after  `out.vcf` is created to signal the completion of the first system command to the `observeEvent`. However, this is an inefficient way as R utilizes the maximum RAM to store the R object. Ideally, it would be sufficient to return the filename signaling that its creation is complete as @r2evans hinted.

Comment: Subsequently, the second system command need to be executed on the file returned by the first system command.  After executing both the system commands inside the `future()`, the output from first system command should be sent to `downloadHandler` and the output from second system command to `renderDataTable`.

Comment: I think you've certainly identified the *"efficient way of doing this"*: in your single `future` block, make the first `system` call, and if its output is good, then make the second system call, and if that output is good, then return from the `future` and signal completion. In your `downloadHandler`, your `content=` argument is something like `function(fn) if (file.exists("previous-out.vcf") file.rename("previous-out.vcf", fn)`.

Comment: i am absolutely stuck there itself i.e. looking for the piece of code that does execute system command and verify that output is good and then execute second command inside future.

Comment: If you don't need to capture the stdout of the command, then with `system2(..., stdout=FALSE)` or `system(..., intern=FALSE)`, the value returned is an error code, "0" for success, non-zero for some error (and that number typically depends on the command called).

Comment: (Though realize you should be using `stdout=some_file_name` to capture the command's output into a file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple "Happy to Glad" converter (and line-numberer).

Goal of this shiny app: given a text file, convert all occurrences of the string `happy` (case-sensitive) with `glad`. An input file, for demonstration:

```
This is a happy file.
It attempts to be very happy.
```

And the sample app, using a simple two-step command process.

**Update**: I've updated it to provide (1) progress, and (2) download of each file. Over to you if you want to disable one or the other download.

```r
library(shiny)
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(transparent)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("\"Happy\" to \"Glad\"!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("infile", "Upload a text file:"),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("act", "Convert!"),
      tags$hr(),
      splitLayout(
        downloadButton("download1", label = "Download 1!"),
        downloadButton("download2", label = "Download 2!")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textAreaInput("intext", label = "Input", rows = 3),
      tags$hr(),
      textAreaInput("outtext", label = "Gladified", rows = 3)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  outfile1 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  outfile2 <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(input$act, {
    req(input$infile)
    prog <- Progress$new(session)
    prog$set(message = "Step 1 in progress",
             detail = "This may take a few moments...",
             value = NULL)
    future({
      Sys.sleep(2)
      outf1 <- tempfile()
      ret1 <- system2("sed", c("-e", "s/happy/glad/g",
                               shQuote(input$infile$datapath)),
                      stdout = outf1)
      if (ret1 == 0L && file.exists(outf1)) {
        outfile1(outf1)
      } else outf1 <- NULL
      outf1
    }) %...>%
      {
        outf1 <- .
        if (is.null(outf1) || !file.exists(outf1)) {
          prog$set(message = "Problems with Step 1?",
                   detail = "(process interrupted ...)",
                   value = NULL)
        } else {
          prog$set(message = "Step 2 in progress",
                   detail = "This may take a few moments...",
                   value = NULL)
        }
        outf1
      } %...>%
      {
        future({
          outf1 <- .
          if (!is.null(outf1inf) && file.exists(outf1)) {
            Sys.sleep(2)
            outf2 <- tempfile()
            ret2 <- system2("cat", c("-n", shQuote(outf1)),
                            stdout = outf2)
            if (ret2 == 0L && file.exists(outf2)) {
              outfile2(outf2)
            } else outf2 <- NULL
          }
          list(outf1, outf2)
        })
      } %...>%
      {
        bothfiles <- .
        if (is.null(bothfiles[[1]])) {
          # do nothing, we already saw the progress-error
        } else if (is.null(bothfiles[[2]]) || !file.exists(bothfiles[[2]])) {
          prog$set(message = "Problems with Step 2?",
                   detail = "(process interrupted ...)",
                   value = NULL)
        }
      } %>%
      finally(~ prog$close())
  })

  observeEvent(input$infile, {
    req(input$infile$datapath, file.exists(input$infile$datapath))
    txt <- readLines(input$infile$datapath, n = 10)
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "intext", value = paste(txt, collapse = "\n"))
  })

  observeEvent(outfile2(), {
    req(outfile2(), file.exists(outfile2()))
    txt <- readLines(outfile2(), n = 10)
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "outtext", value = paste(txt, collapse = "\n"))
  })

  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      req(input$infile)
      paste0(basename(input$infile$name), "_gladified")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      req(outfile1())
      file.copy(outfile1(), file)
    }
  )

  output$download2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      req(input$infile)
      paste0(basename(input$infile$name), "_gladified_and_numbered")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      req(outfile2())
      file.copy(outfile2(), file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Notes:

- It is not very smart, so for each `if (ret1 == 0L)`, you should have an `else` clause that presents some error message to the user if non-zero;
- It is a little inefficient in that it makes a copy of the output file instead of renaming it. I chose this because renaming it would allow a download only once.
- I haven't spent a lot of time troubleshooting what happens with failed processing; while I think the progress markers I've put in are decent, you might want more testing of fail-states;
- It would likely be useful to include judicious use of `shinyjs::toggleState` on the download buttons so that you can't download what does not exist.
- And finally, I'm not truly thrilled with having such a gargantuan `observeEvent` with multiple `future` steps; it'd be nice to `function`-ize the steps or generalize for an arbitrary number of steps.

[image: screenshot of shiny app, mid-process]

Comment: This is not technically "signalling on file-creation", as that might suggest use of `shiny::reactiveFileReader`. Not horrible, granted, but I feel that polling can be unnecessary, especially when we control both the file creation and use.

Comment: little confused, `outfile()` is returning the output from second system command whereas the `downloadHandler` is required to get the output from first system command.

Comment: also how could we embed the progress status of the `future` as in the OP.

Comment: If you need `outfile()` to point to file1, then ... point it to file1. I'll edit and show what I mean ... it's just a pointer to the file you want.

Comment: i will give a try and then accept the answer!!  And could u elaborate on functionizing as it may be crucial for my app to implement such functions.

Comment: I prefer to keep my `server` components as short as possible, using semantic function names. While I don't assume that a function will be used more than once (a common reason to convert a process into a generalized function), if nothing else it makes the intent of that `observe` block much more self-evident, while still allowing you to see neighboring `output$`/`reactive`/`observe` chunks clearly. Once you start working with shiny modules, it becomes a lot more evident how to do this, but that takes time (and is out of scope for this Q/A).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196946/discussion-between-chas-and-r2evans).

Comment: Whenever you deal with promises and a `{...}` block of code, the data from the previous promise is passed into this block as `.`. Most of the time, I find it useful for visualizing code to reassign it, but `.` can still technically be used. Some of the time, it is actually *required* to assign it elsewhere, as in when the dot is interpreted specially within other function calls (e.g., other promises, many `dplyr` or related functions, etc).

Comment: And neither `outfile(outf1)` nor `outf1` nor is used in the second system command. Could lmk how to use `outf1` in the second system command as input?

Comment: (1) In the *second* system command, why would you want to change the `reactiveVal` of `outf1`? It should already have been set earlier in the promise-chain. (2) I named the *input filename* for any of the blocks `inf` for consistency (I thought it might make it easier to extend later), but for clarity (though with slight loss of generality), I just changed `inf` to be `outf1` or `bothfiles`, depending on its location in the chain.

Comment: Please don't edit an *answer* to extend your *question*. I don't have your code, as this answer works as-is. The [link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-future-error-in-ctx-oninvalidate-reactive-context-was-created-in-one-process-and-accessed-from-another/17349/3) might be appropriate, but only in the context of your code. I suggest you open a new question.